# Express.js 4.x session undefined after migration from 3.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have migrated my application from Express.js 3.x to 4.x. I have done all changes described in migration guide. Unfortunately, when I try to get session from request object it is undefined.

That is how I set express.js as far as cookie parser and session are concerned:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: false, secure: false, maxAge: null }
}));
```

Then when I try to get session from request:

```
req.session.cookie.maxAge
```

session is undefined. I have no clue why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out that there were two app.use():

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).write('500');
    res.end();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(config.root + '/html/404.html');
});
```

after the old:

```
app.use(app.router);
```

which is removed in 4.x version. And after those app.use() there were routes definitions.

I missed that when migrating to express 4.x all calls to app.use() should be moved after all routes.
When I have done it, everything is all right.

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.0, a lot of middleware is no longer bundled with Express. See the [migration docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x). You need to `npm install --save express-session` and `app.use require` it.

Comment: As I said before, I have done it. I have done all changes described in migration docs.

Comment: In this case, check if you define routes before or after the session middleware. If routes come first, they probably don't have req.session. Shift things around and see if this makes a difference.